# implementing complex number power function in c++?

Tags: c++, class, operator-overloading

Like the title said, i'm trying to implement an operator^(int n) which will calculate a complex number to the nth power. I know that `this` is a pointer that point to the current class object so i came up with this code:

```
    class Complex{
    protected:
      float a,b;
    public:
      Complex() {a=0;b=0;}
      Complex(float x, float y){a=x;b=y;}
      void set(float x, float y){a=x;b=y;}
      Complex operator*(Complex C){
                Complex temp;
                temp.a=a*C.a-b*C.b;
                temp.b=a*C.b+b*C.a;
                return temp;
      }
      Complex operator^(int n){
                Complex ONE=Complex(1,0);
                if (n<=0) return ONE;
                return ((*this)*((*this)^(n-1)));
      }
      void Display(){
                cout<<a<<' '<<b<<endl;
      }
      };
      int main() {
          Complex C;
          C.set(2,0);
          C=C^3;
          C.Display();
      }
```

The C.Display() is supposed to print `8 0` but when i ran in eclipse it display `2 0`. Please tell me why this happens. Also really appreciate if anyone could tell me how to make `ONE` at line 15 a constant class object like BigInteger.ONE in Java.

Comment: Even though it's tempting – please don't use `^` as a power operator in C++, it has the wrong precedence.

Comment: What's wrong with `std::complex` and `std::pow`?

Comment: @leftaroundabout sorry but i couldn't find any operator better than ^ for power.

Comment: @minhnhat93: So use a named function, instead of an operator.  No C++ (or C#, or Java) programmer expects power to be an operator.

Comment: @Fanael This is my homework for Class and Struct lecture and it says i have to implement an operator for the power function

Comment: @minhnhat93, then you should change place where you are taking lectures; no sane lecturer will tell you to use `operator^()` as power in C++.

Comment: @Griwes: Changing course might not be an option, but he should do it the right way (a function named `pow`) and be prepared to defend that by pointing out that the C++ Standard Committee, who are no fools, decided that was the better approach.

Comment: @BenVoigt, true, but he doesn't seem interested in sane solutions.

Comment: please go easy on me. this is my homework, what else can I do? and nobody's answering my question?

Comment: Perhaps the answers are a bit vague because we cannot find any errors. The code works fine for me...

Comment: @minhnhat93: Are you sure this is the code that prints `2 0`? It prints `8 0` as expected for me: see http://ideone.com/MatpM (Also, please ignore anything your lecturer tries to teach you about C++, and read [a good book](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/388242) instead).

Comment: @MikeSeymour this is strange, it still show `2 0` on my computer, perhap this is because of the compiler. it seems that the problem has been solved. thank you all for the help :)), love you all. and i'll find my new c++ book too :D

Answer (score 3):

Are you aware that there is an [std::complex](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/numeric/complex) template type, with its own [std::pow](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/numeric/complex/pow) specialization?

```
#include <complex>
#include <iostream>

int main() {

  std::complex<double> c(2,0);
  std::complex<double> c3 = pow(c, 3);
  std::cout << c3 << "\n";
}
```

produces

> (8,0)

furthermore, `operator^` is bitwise XOR. Reusing this as a power operator will result in very confusing code.

Other than that, your code produces the result you expect, so the problem must lie elsewhere.

Comment: No need to qualify `pow` with `std::`, because ADL will find the right function.

Comment: yeah, i searched but i NEED to implement operator^ for this is homework

Comment: @minhnhat93 well, your code has many problems, but at least it produces the result you expect, so I don't know what is going on.

Answer (score 1):

> Also really appreciate if anyone could tell me how to make ONE at line 15 a constant class object like BigInteger.ONE in Java.

Put this inside your Complex declaration:

```
class Complex {
   ...
   const static Complex ONE;
};
```

And, put this outside your Complex declaration:

```
const Complex Complex::ONE(1,0);
```

If you put your Complex declaration inside a header file (e.g., Complex.hpp), you should the 2nd line (the Complex::ONE definition) inside *exactly one* source-code file (e.g. Complex.cpp).

Comment: This kills optimization though... therefore not recommended.  Better is `class Complex { /*...*/ public: static Complex ONE() { return Complex(1,0); } }`; which will be inlined and optimized away.

Comment: thanks Rob :D but can you please tell me why we need to write `const static` and not `const` only?

Comment: The `static` keyword in this context specifies a *static data member*. A static data member is not part of any object, but exists once for all objects of that class. This is similar to what Java calls a *class variable*. If that is not the behavior you asked for, disregard my answer.

Comment: it worked perfectly, i asked because i want to understand things clearly. thank you!